# Testing with fake model data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocking

Let's say I have a simple function on a class that takes a model object, transforms the data, and then returns a hash. Something like:

```
def model_to_hash(some_model)
  # transform model data into new hash structure
  # return the new hash
end
```

I want to test that data with sample data from the model in question. What is a good strategy for doing this?

Of course, one could mock an instance of model with dummy data in the test file or in a fixture file, but that test data could go out of sync with the actual model's attributes.

Is there a way to do this that is more directly linked to the the model using something like rspec?

Comment: When you say "that test data could go out of sync with the actual model", does "the actual model" refer to data in your development database? A fundamental concept in testing is that the tests are not "connected" to data outside your test.

Comment: @jvillian I mean more that the something about the model could change, e.g. some attribute is add/removed/changed. The specific data in question I assume would be just dummy data.

Comment: If you use rspec and something like FactoryBot (or some other test fixture) and ensure that you've done `rake db:test:prepare`, then the structure of your models should be identical in your test and development environments.